# bash permissions using softperms.txt file

Tags: php, wordpress, bash

I have a file called softperms.txt
formatted as so

```html
<br>

/ 0751<br>
xmlrpc.php 0644<br>
wp-activate.php 0644<br>
wp-mail.php 0644<br>
<br>
```

I would like to use a bash command to write these permissions. I know it exists. Maybe a bash veteran can help me out? 
Thanks

Comment: Hello. I see you are new here. You should know that this isn't a code writing service. You should try something first. Then post the code. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, have you already read the following? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a short program like this:

```
while 
  read filespec permissions 
do
  chmod $permissions $filespec
done < softperms.txt
```